# How does tf.audio.decode_wav get its contents?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to pull some audio files into Tensorflow by using `tf.audio.decode_wav`.

I can see someone is looking into providing more info in the docs, but does anyone have any examples of how this should work?

```
tf.audio.decode_wav(
 contents,
 desired_channels=-1,
 desired_samples=-1,
 name=None
)
```

**Args:**

- contents: A Tensor of type string. The WAV-encoded audio, usually from a file.
- desired_channels: An optional int. Defaults to -1. Number of sample channels wanted.
- desired_samples: An optional int. Defaults to -1. Length of audio requested.
- name: A name for the operation (optional).

I'm guessing the contents is a tensor which has already been pulled from a file rather than a path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, `tf.audio.decode_wav()` requires a tensor. You can provide one with 
`tf.io.read_file()` which reads wav file into tensor of type string.

```
raw_audio = tf.io.read_file(filename)
waveform = tf.audio.decode_wav(raw_audio)
```

Comment: BTW, how to get shape of waveform? it seems `get_shape()` simply gives `(None, ch)`.

Comment: Could be done with `tf.enable_eager_execution()`, but is there a way without it?