# Extracting Audio channel from a video file to feed in decode_wav function of TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, wav

I want to feed audio channel of a video file to the following TenorFlow function:

```
tf.audio.decode_wav(
contents,
desired_channels=-1,
desired_samples=-1,
name=None)
```

Where Args:

- contents: A Tensor of type string. The WAV-encoded audio, usually
  from a file.
- desired_channels: An optional int. Defaults to -1. Number of sample
  channels wanted.
- desired_samples: An optional int. Defaults to -1. Length of audio
  requested.
- name: A name for the operation (optional).

Comment: Check those answers: [How does tf.audio.decode_wav get its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096095/how-does-tf-audio-decode-wav-get-its-contents) & [Python extract wav from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741116/python-extract-wav-from-video-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the audio of video by eg.:

```py
import subprocess

command = "ffmpeg -i C:/test.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav"

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

And pass the `*.wav` file as tensor to `tf.audio.decode_wav`:

```py
raw_audio = tf.io.read_file(filename)
waveform = tf.audio.decode_wav(raw_audio)
```

References:

- [Python extract wav from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741116/python-extract-wav-from-video-file)
- [How does tf.audio.decode_wav get its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096095/how-does-tf-audio-decode-wav-get-its-contents)

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10, I solved my problem this way:

1. I downloaded and installed ffmpeg for windows [from here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
2. Extracted wav audio files from videos as:

   ```
   import os,shlex, subprocess
   files = os.listdir('.')
   #convert all video files of the current directory to wav audio files
   for f in files:
       if(f.endswith('.wmv') or f.endswith('.mp4') or f.endswith('.avi')):
           command_line = "ffmpeg -i "+f+" -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn "+f[0:-4]+".wav"
           #command_line = "ffmpeg -i default.wmv -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn default.wav"
           args = shlex.split(command_line)
           print(args)
           p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
           print(p)
   ```
3. Decoded audio files to wavform as:

   ```
       import tensorflow as tf
   files = os.listdir('.')
   #convert all video files of the current directory to wav audio files
   for filename in files:
       if(filename.endswith('.wav')):
           print(filename)
           audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(filename,name=None)
           waveform,_ = tf.audio.decode_wav(
               audio_binary,
               desired_channels=-1,
               desired_samples=-1,
               name=None
           )
   ```